# "Operator called default onErrorDropped" on Mono timeout

Tags: project-reactor

In my Production code, I am getting errors in my logs when a Mono times out.
I have managed to recreate these errors with the following code:

```
@Test
public void testScheduler() {
    Mono<String> callableMethod1 = callableMethod();
    callableMethod1.block();

    Mono<String> callableMethod2 = callableMethod();
    callableMethod2.block();
}

private Mono<String> callableMethod() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(60);
        return "Success";
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(50))
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just("Timeout"));
}
```

In the `Mono.fromCallable` I am making a blocking call using a third-party library. When this call times out, I get errors similar to

```
reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception
```

These errors also seem to be intermittent, sometimes when I run the code provided I get no errors at all. However when I repeat the call in a loop of say 10, I consistently get them.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The question is why does this error happen, and what can I do to get rid of them. It does not seem to affect the code, but I was wondering if this is pointing to something missing in my code

Comment: Have a look at the "Dropping Hooks" section, this might help you to figure out why the onErrorDropped hook is called in your case: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/advancedFeatures.adoc#dropping-hooks

Comment: @rival the link is broken.

Comment: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/main/docs/asciidoc/advancedFeatures.adoc - working link for link shared by @rival

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Question**: Why does this error happen?

**Answer**:

When the duration given to the *timeout()* operator has passed, it throws a *TimeoutException*. That results in the following outcomes:

1. An *onError* signal is sent to the main reactive chain. As a result, the main execution is resumed and the process moves on (i.e., *onErrorResume()* is executed).
2. Shortly after outcome #1, the async task defined within *fromCallable()* is interrupted, which triggers a 2nd exception (*InterruptedException*). The main reactive chain can no longer handle this *InterruptedException* because the *TimeoutException* happened first and already caused the main reactive chain to resume (**Note:** this behavior of not generating a 2nd *onError* signal conforms with the Reactive Stream Specification -> [Publisher #7](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/master/README.md#1.7)).

Since the 2nd exception (*InterruptedException*) can't be handled gracefully by the main chain, Reactor logs it at error level to let us know an unexpected exception occurred.

**Question**: How do I get rid of them?

**Short Answer**: Use [Hooks.onErrorDropped()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#hooks-dropping) to change the log level:

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Hooks.onErrorDropped(error -> {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception happened:", error);
        });

        Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(60);
            return "Success";
        })
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
         .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(50))
         .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just("Timeout"))
         .doOnSuccess(result -> logger.info("Result: " + result))
         .block();
     }
```

**Long Answer**: If your use-case allows, you could handle the exception happening within *fromCallable()* so that the only exception affecting the main chain is the *TimeoutException*. In that case, the *onErrorDropped()* wouldn't happen in the first place.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //release resources, rollback actions, etc
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Something went wrong...", ex);
        }
        return "Success";
    })
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
     .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(50))
     .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just("Timeout"))
     .doOnSuccess(result -> logger.info("Result: " + result))
     .block();
}
```

Extra References:

- https://tacogrammer.com/onerrordropped-explained/
- https://medium.com/@kalpads/configuring-timeouts-in-spring-reactive-webclient-4bc5faf56411