# Spring Webflux Reactor WebClient onErrorDropped

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

Note: reactor-core: 3.3.3.Release
Related issue: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1783, but I'm not smart enough to understand it.

Scenario. My program is making http requests to multiple endpoints, using separate webclient instances. If both endpoints are down, both connections gets cancelled, but only one is captured on subscriber. Below is my test code

```
package org.example.webclient;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelException;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LogLevel;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient;

import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public class WebClientTest {

    private WebClient webClient() {
        TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                .doOnConnected(connection ->
                        connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10000))
                                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10000))
                                .addHandlerLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE)));
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    private Flux<String> getEndpointsFlux() {
        List<String> endpoints = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8091",
                "http://localhost:8092"));
        return Flux.fromIterable(endpoints);
    }

    private Flux<String> sendRequest(String endpoint) {
        return this.webClient().post()
                .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
                .body(Mono.just("test"), String.class)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    HttpStatus statusCode = clientResponse.statusCode();
                    if (statusCode.is4xxClientError() || statusCode.is5xxServerError()) {
                        String response = null;
                        log.error("Client/Server Error while connecting to endpoint {} code {} ",
                                endpoint, statusCode);
                        return Mono.error(new SendFailedException(endpoint, statusCode.toString()));
                    }
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                })
                .onErrorResume(ChannelException.class, e -> {
                    log.error("Timeout Exception while connecting to endpoint {} {}",
                            endpoint, e.getMessage());
                    return Mono.error(new SendFailedException(endpoint, "timeout"));
                })
                .onErrorResume(ConnectException.class, e -> {
                    log.error("Connection Exception while connecting to endpoint {} {}",
                            endpoint, e.getMessage());
                    return Mono.error(new SendFailedException(endpoint, "connect_failed"));
                })
                .doOnCancel(()-> {
                    log.error("Cancelled client {}", endpoint);
                    Mono.error(new SendFailedException(endpoint, "client_cancelled"));
                })
                .flux();
    }

    private void onCompleted(String response) {
        log.info("On Completed {}", response);
    }

    private void onFailed(Throwable e) {
        log.info("On Failed {} {}", ((SendFailedException)e).endpoint, ((SendFailedException)e).getMessage());
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        WebClientTest webClientTest = new WebClientTest();
        webClientTest.getEndpointsFlux()
                .flatMap(webClientTest::sendRequest)
                .subscribe(webClientTest::onCompleted, webClientTest::onFailed);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class SendFailedException extends Exception {
        String endpoint;
        String message;
        SendFailedException(String endpoint, String message) {
            super(message);
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can read from the code, if both endpoints are down, I do expect call to **onFailed** twice. But it is called only once. Attached the response below.

```
11:29:59.103 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
11:29:59.172 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
11:29:59.218 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
11:29:59.225 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
11:29:59.226 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 8
11:29:59.229 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
11:29:59.231 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
11:29:59.232 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
11:29:59.233 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: available
11:29:59.235 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
11:29:59.235 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable prior to Java9
11:29:59.235 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
11:29:59.236 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
11:29:59.236 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\wjose\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
11:29:59.237 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
11:29:59.239 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 3790077952 bytes
11:29:59.240 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
11:29:59.242 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava6 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
11:29:59.242 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
11:29:59.246 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
11:29:59.246 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
11:29:59.946 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
11:29:59.948 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
11:30:00.025 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [tcp] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-tcp, daemon=true, selectCount=4, workerCount=4}
11:30:00.025 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [tcp] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider@1d8d30f7
11:30:01.379 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
11:30:01.379 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
11:30:01.410 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=4, workerCount=4}
11:30:01.410 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources - [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider@173ed316
11:30:01.416 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll - Default Epoll support : false
11:30:01.418 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue - Default KQueue support : false
11:30:01.425 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
11:30:01.453 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
11:30:01.453 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
11:30:01.463 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
11:30:01.463 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
11:30:01.474 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
11:30:02.234 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [4738a206] HTTP POST http://localhost:8091
11:30:02.242 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - Creating a new client pool [PoolFactory {maxConnections=500, pendingAcquireMaxCount=-1, pendingAcquireTimeout=45000, maxIdleTime=-1, maxLifeTime=-1, metricsEnabled=false}] for [localhost:8091]
11:30:02.307 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 20752 (auto-detected)
11:30:02.873 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: 7c:2a:31:ff:fe:e3:91:99 (auto-detected)
11:30:02.928 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 8
11:30:02.928 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 8
11:30:02.928 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
11:30:02.928 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
11:30:02.928 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
11:30:02.929 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
11:30:02.944 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
11:30:02.944 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
11:30:02.944 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
11:30:02.949 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [1187c9e8] HTTP POST http://localhost:8092
11:30:02.949 [main] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - Creating a new client pool [PoolFactory {maxConnections=500, pendingAcquireMaxCount=-1, pendingAcquireTimeout=45000, maxIdleTime=-1, maxLifeTime=-1, metricsEnabled=false}] for [localhost:8092]
11:30:02.960 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x947cb6eb] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
11:30:02.960 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0xc4ac08e3] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
11:30:03.019 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
11:30:03.020 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
11:30:03.021 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@470a0273
11:30:03.033 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers - [id: 0x947cb6eb] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
11:30:03.033 [reactor-http-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers - [id: 0xc4ac08e3] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
11:30:04.061 [reactor-http-nio-1] ERROR org.example.webclient.WebClientTest - Connection Exception while connecting to endpoint http://localhost:8091 Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8091
11:30:04.061 [reactor-http-nio-2] ERROR org.example.webclient.WebClientTest - Connection Exception while connecting to endpoint http://localhost:8092 Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8092
11:30:04.063 [reactor-http-nio-2] ERROR org.example.webclient.WebClientTest - Cancelled client http://localhost:8091
11:30:04.063 [reactor-http-nio-2] ERROR org.example.webclient.WebClientTest - Cancelled client http://localhost:8092
11:30:04.063 [reactor-http-nio-2] INFO org.example.webclient.WebClientTest - On Failed connect_failed
11:30:04.066 [reactor-http-nio-1] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
org.example.webclient.WebClientTest$SendFailedException: connect_failed
    at org.example.webclient.WebClientTest.lambda$sendRequest$3(WebClientTest.java:72)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$31(Mono.java:3351)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1944)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:390)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:197)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryPredicate.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$TcpClientSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:346)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(PooledConnectionProvider.java:468)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:381)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.lambda$drainLoop$7(SimplePool.java:206)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.doError(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onError(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:282)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:232)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11:30:04.067 [reactor-http-nio-1] WARN io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise - An exception was thrown by reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete()
reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: org.example.webclient.WebClientTest$SendFailedException: connect_failed
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.bubble(Exceptions.java:170)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onErrorDropped(Operators.java:590)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerError(FluxFlatMap.java:843)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:979)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1944)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:390)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:197)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryPredicate.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$TcpClientSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:346)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(PooledConnectionProvider.java:468)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:381)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.lambda$drainLoop$7(SimplePool.java:206)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.doError(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onError(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:282)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:232)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.example.webclient.WebClientTest$SendFailedException: connect_failed
    at org.example.webclient.WebClientTest.lambda$sendRequest$3(WebClientTest.java:72)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$31(Mono.java:3351)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Is it a problem with netty making concurrent requests or problem with flux? In fact, I can redesign my code to use mono rather Flux. But eventually it ends up in several webclients being concurrently executed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433079/operator-called-default-onerrordropped-on-mono-timeout does this help?

Comment: I shall look into that. Now trying to refactor the code to avoid flux